# Cross-thread operation not valid control

Tags: c#, thread-safety, invoke

I know there are many topcis about my question but I can't find a solution for my case...

I have a panel which I add controls on it at runtime, I tried this code but it doesn't help me, and an error says :

> cross-thread operation not valid control 'panel1' accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created on

Here my code :

```
public void AddControlToPanel(Panel panel, Control ctrl)
{
    if (panel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        panel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { AddControlToPanel(panel, ctrl); });
        return;
    }
    else
        panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

and I call this like this :

```
AddControlToPanel(panel1, ctrl);
```

Comment: As far as I see this should be correct. Is the `panel.Invoke(...)` called?

Comment: Why are you using a recursive call for this? why not just call panel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { panel.Controls.Add(ctrl); }); if panel.InvokeRequired is true?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: It is a common pattern in WinForms to do so...

Comment: Was your control created on the same thread as panel1?  If not then that's your problem.

Comment: @shf301 sorry I don't understand your comment, please explain it

Comment: Was your form created on a different thread than the UI Thread?

Comment: @aEkBKF winforms controls have thread affinity so it matters which thread that they were created on, that is which thread was running when new was called.  If panel1 was created on the main thread and ctrl was created in a background thread they cannot be used together since they are "owned" by different threads.

Comment: IMO this code is correct, and the problem is somewhere else, this might be a problem of InvokeRequired not being set before IsHandleCreated, even if invoke is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I solved my problem, my code was correct, just Hide old controls to show new ones, using this nice function :

```
private void SetControlPropertyValue(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue)
        {
            if (oControl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetControlValueCallback d = new SetControlValueCallback(SetControlPropertyValue);
                oControl.Invoke(d, new object[] { oControl, propName, propValue });
            }
            else
            {
                Type t = oControl.GetType();
                PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
                {
                    if (p.Name.ToUpper() == propName.ToUpper())
                    {
                        p.SetValue(oControl, propValue, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

like this :

```
foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls.OfType<Type>())
                {
                    SetControlPropertyValue(item, "Visible", false);                 
                }
```

and then, I can recreate my controls like this:

```
AddControlToPanel(panel1, ctrl);
```

Thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a control extension within your project's namespace like this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void UIThread(this Control @this, Action code)
    {
        if (null != @this && (!@this.Disposing || !@this.IsDisposed))
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.BeginInvoke(code);
            }
            else
            {
                code.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it within your code like this:

```
this.UIThread(() =>
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
});
```

Comment: But doesn't that execute exactly the same as he is already doing hence not solve his problem? But still a very nice extensions!

Comment: There is no difference, you just exported it to a nice extension method :)

Comment: I use this ext on quite allot of my project needing cross thread operation and it works. Not sure why this would throw the same error.

Comment: It would throw the same error as it executes the same logic. His problem must lay elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should also be checking for "IsHandleCreated"

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): 
...InvokeRequired can return false if Invoke is not required (the call occurs on the same thread), or if the control was created on a different thread but the control's handle has not yet been created.

...

You can protect against this case by also checking the value of IsHandleCreated when InvokeRequired returns false on a background thread. If the control handle has not yet been created, you must wait until it has been created before calling Invoke or BeginInvoke. Typically, this happens only if a background thread is created in the constructor of the primary form for the application (as in Application.Run(new MainForm()), before the form has been shown or Application.Run has been called.